# Using operator new, but not calling the constructor

Tags: c++, new-operator, undefined-behavior

Does the following code result in an undefined behavior? I never call a constructor of T (directly or indirectly).

```
struct T {
  void sample() { }
  int *a;
  int *b; };

int main()  {
  T* ptr = reinterpret_cast<T*>(operator new(sizeof(T)));    
  ptr->a = new int(1);
  ptr->b = new int(2);
  ptr->sample();
  delete ptr; }
```

Comment: Then why not simply write `T* ptr = new T;`? Will do exactly the same thing, more readable **and you are sure there is no undefined behavior** and also avoid somewhat dangerous `reinterpret_cast` which can also lead to UB if used improperly. Even better would be to use `std::unique_ptr<T>` instead of raw pointer.

Comment: **[basic.life](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life)**: "The lifetime of an object of type T begins when: (1.1) storage ... is obtained, and (1.2) if the object has non-vacuous initialization, its initialization is complete." You satisfied requirement 1.1 by allocating memory, but you did not satisfy (1.2) because your object has non-vacuous initialization (it has a user-defined constructor) that has not completed. The behavior is undefined if between (1.1) and (1.2) "the pointer is used to access a non-static data member" which you have done.

Comment: @RaymondChen `T` does not in fact appear to have a user-defined constructor.

Comment: @Phil1970 This is a code that only shows the problem. In the scenario that made me post this question, I cannot call `new T`. What that scenario is or alternative methods are out of the scope of this post.

Comment: @RaymondChen Why (1.2) is not satisfied? 
"An object is said to have non-vacuous initialization if it is of a class or aggregate type and it or one of its subobjects is initialized by a constructor other than a trivial default constructor."
Based on the link that you sent, I would say what I wrote is in fact well defined.

Comment: Sorry, I thought `sample()` was the constructor. So it looks like condition 1.2 is satisfied. You have an object. You can always use placement new to run the constructor. That would remove the triviality requirement.

Comment: @Koosha That kind of code is very fragile because there is no check made and a constructor can easily be added during maintenant either directly or by adding a member that has one and the compiler might not necessarily complain. **Why not use placement new to make the code less fragile if you really need to manually allocate the memory?** That is something like, `void *memory = operator new(sizeof(T)); T *ptr = new (memory) T; `. Event then, I don't easily see cases where that where that could be helpful and there are no appropriate alternative like using vector, variant, any...

Comment: As written, this is a poor question because you don't give context or motivation of writing that kind of code which **should be rejected at code review** without a good reason **and without better alternative**. And we don't like to encourage people write poor code.